# Missing user password with parse REST Api when linking facebook user

Tags: facebook, rest, symfony, curl, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement Facebook login under a Symfony2 project using parse.com REST Api.

Here is the code I'm using for making the CURL call:

```
$headers = array(
"Content-Type: application/json",
"Content-Length: " . strlen($facebookJson),
"X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $applicationId,
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $parseRestAPIKey
);

$handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $facebookJson); 

$data = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```

The `$facebookJson` variable represents the Facebook authData:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "id": "user's Facebook id number as a string",
    "access_token": "an authorized Facebook access token for the user",
    "expiration_date": "token expiration date of the format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
  }
}
```

In this example, the user is not a registered user in parse, so it should create a new user (as stated in [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-linking)), but instead of creating a new user, it gives the following error message:

> "{"code":201,"error":"missing user password"}

Since I'm using Facebook to register the user, I don't think it should ask for a password, [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-linking) doesn't mention this.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Should I try a different approach in order to implement Facebook login with parse? (may be it's easier with parse javascript sdk for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed *authData* field. Here is the example of JSON from Parse documentation:

```
{
    "authData": {
        "twitter": {
            "id": "12345678",
            "screen_name": "ParseIt",
            "consumer_key": "SaMpLeId3X7eLjjLgWEw",
            "consumer_secret": "SaMpLew55QbMR0vTdtOACfPXa5UdO2THX1JrxZ9s3c",
            "auth_token": "12345678-SaMpLeTuo3m2avZxh5cjJmIrAfx4ZYyamdofM7IjU",
            "auth_token_secret": "SaMpLeEb13SpRzQ4DAIzutEkCE2LBIm2ZQDsP3WUU"
        }
    }
}
```